# Javascript strip all url parameters from string?

Tags: javascript

I've got an URL in a string like this:

```
http://url.com?page=121&param1=hello&param2=bye#hello
```

The above could be something else as well meaning it will be dynamic.

How could I only keep the "main page"? In the above it would be:

```
http://url.com?page=121
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? This is *basic* string manipulation.

Comment: Just use a regular expression.

Comment: `"http://url.com?page=121&param1=hello&param2=bye#hello".split('&')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://url.com?page=121&param1=hello&param2=bye#hello";
```

Just find the `&` and cut with `indexof()`.

```
var mainPage = url.substring(0,url.indexof("&"));
```

or `split()`

```
var mainPage = url.split("&")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getUrl(url, param) 
{ 
   return url.split("&")[param].split("#")[param]; 
}
```

or simply

```
function getUrl(url) {
  return url.split("&")[0];
}
```

Comment: how can he get the `?page=123` part if he cuts the `?`